# Jboss Oracle JDBC connection failed

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jboss, oracle11g

Jboss EAP 6.3, Oracle 11g Express.
I have this oracle datasource in standalone:

```
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</connection-url>
                <driver>oracleDriver</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>Boris</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="oracleDriver" module="com.oracle">
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

The Oracle database is running, I can connect to it using sqlplus:

```
SQL> connect
Enter user-name: Boris
Enter password: 
Connected.
```

The datasource shows up in the Jboss admin panel. I run a test connection, but it responds with:

```
Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "OracleDS")
    ],
    "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation: JBAS010447: Connection is not valid",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

And in the jboss console I found this:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL lev
el 1
ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified
```

but the solutions to that error I found on the internet didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ORA-12705` error suggests that this might be a locale issue. You could try starting up JBoss with a locale that is [supported by Oracle XE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#XEINL138) when converted into an NLS. For example, try adding this to your JBoss startup configuration (`JAVA_OPTS` variable in `jboss-as/bin/run.conf`):

```
-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US
```